# Querying nested objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I have a Product-Merchant mapping which looks like the following

```
  catalog_map = {

        "catalog": {
            "properties": {
                "merchant_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                },
                "products": {
                    "type": "object",
                },
                "merchant_name" :{
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

"product" has objects, say , product_id , product_name , product_price. Products and merchants are mapped, such that :

```
    for merchant in Merchant.objects.all() :

        products = [{"product_name" : x.product.name, "product_price" : x.price, "product_id" : x.product.id , "product_category" : x.product.category.name} for x in MerchantProductMapping.objects.filter(merchant=merchant)]

        tab = {
            'merchant_id': merchant.id,
            'merchant_name': merchant.name,
            'product': products
            }

       res = es.index(index="my-index", doc_type='catalog', body=tab)
```

The data gets indexed smoothly, in the desired form. Now, when I query the data from given index, I do it in the following way :

```
GET /esearch-index/catalog/_search
{ 
"query": {
"bool" :{
    "must": [
       {"match": {
          "merchant_name": {
              "query": "Sir John"
          }
       }}], 
       "should": [
          {"match": {
             "product_name": {
                 "query": "Vanilla"
             }
          }}
       ]
    }}
```

This query gives me the result of all the products in the index with merchant name "Sir John" . However, **I want it to return the details of the product "Vanilla" sold by "Sir John" instead.**

On someone's recommendation, I used "_source" while querying, but that doesn't help.

**How can I single out the information of one single object from the entire "catalog" index of the merchant?**

Comment: it's not clear from your question what the structure of your data is. The documentation on [nesting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) has a good explanation of the flattening that happens in Elasticsearch - this might be the cause of the query issue. Ways round it include using  [explicit nesting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) or a [child document](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html).

Answer (score 2):

Once your **bool query** has a **must** clause, all the conditions inside of it are required. The conditions inside of the **should** clause are not required. They will only boost the results. (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query)

So, going back to your query, it will retrieve all catalogs matching merchant_name "Sir John". This is the only required (must) condition. The name "Vanilla" will only boost results with the name "Vanilla" to the top, because it is not required.

If you want to retrieve "Vanilla" sold by "Sir John", put both conditions inside of the must clause and change your query to this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "merchant_name": {
              "query": "Sir John"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "product_name": {
              "query": "Vanilla"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```